# How to only accept unique values in a number input type in a form in html?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, user-input

I have a form with number input types, and I have limited responses to be between 1 and 14. However, I want to make the user input only unique numbers between 1 and 14. For example, if they put "2" for three different input boxes, I want a warning to pop up and not let them submit until they fix that.

Someone helped me and gave me this, however it does not seem to work. Am I not using it properly?

```
document.getElementById("formName").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // Here you get all unique-number inputs.
  var inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('unique'));
  
  // After that you map each input.
  var values = inputs.map(function(input) {
    return parseInt(input. Value, 10);
  });

  // An if to know if there are any duplicate values.
  if (hasDuplicates(values)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please ensure all numbers are unique.");
  }
});

function hasDuplicates(array) {
  var valueCount = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (valueCount[array[i]]) {
      return true;
    }
    valueCount[array[i]] = true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

This is how my number inputs look.

```
<label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br>
```

I have included the javascript into my htmlpage using
`<script src="script.js"> </script>`

Am I implementing the code wrong into my html? Does it actually not work? Please help, thank you!

Comment: You have an extra backslash at the beginning. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Why are you using base 14 in your call to `parseInput()`?

Comment: Hello, both of those were copying errors, I apologize! It should be base 10. @Barmar

Comment: What's stopping you from editing the question to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my benchmarking (below the answer) using `Set` is the fastest way to handle unique values:

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("formName").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  
  const values = Array.from(e.target.querySelectorAll('.unique'))
    .map(input => parseInt(input.value)).filter(num => num === num);

  try {

    // An if to know if there are any duplicate values.
    if (!isUnique(values)) {
      throw new Error("Please ensure all numbers are unique.");
    }
  
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);  
    e.preventDefault();  
  }
  
  
});

function isUnique(arr) {
  const set = new Set;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const val = arr[i];
      if (set.has(val)) {
          return false;
      }
      set.add(val);
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="formName">
<label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br><label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br><label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br><label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br><label><input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="14" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 14')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="unique"> <span>Mark Twain</span></label>
<br>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```html
<body></body>
<script name="benchmark" data-count="1">

    const count = 1000000;
    const arr = Array.from({ length: count }, () => Math.random());

    function isUnique(arr) {
        const set = new Set;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const val = arr[i];
            if (set.has(val)) {
                return false;
            }
            set.add(val);
        }
        return true;

    }
    function isUnique2(arr) {
        const set = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const val = arr[i];
            if (val in set) {
                return false;
            }
            set[val] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // @benchmark using Set
    isUnique(arr);

    // @benchmark using object
    isUnique2(arr);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, when I press submit the alert always pops up regardless of whether the values were unique or not. Once I got my original code to work, I was having the same issue of always firing the alert. What do you think could be causing this? I'm new to JS so debugging has not gone well :( Thank you!!

Comment: It seems like the problem is that it requires all input fields to be filled, and while there are empty inputs the error message will continue to run. My form does not need every question to be answered, but if they all are, THEN they must be a unique number from 1-14.

Comment: @NildaJarero fixed, enjoy